# Edit border on outlook emails

Tags: email, outlook, html-email, outlook-2013

I am developing the HTML code for an email and I can't figure out why are the images selectable on Outlook 2013. When the user clicks on them Outlooks shows a dashed border around, which I would like to avoid. Is there any CSS property or something I can use for this purpose?

[image: Printscreen]

I have tried to set the CSS properties `outline` and `border` to none, without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an Outlook 'feature'. You can't turn this off.